# implementing a custom recyclerView with checkbox

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a `RecyclerView` whose item has checkboxes so that they sort of can emulate item selection, for this I created a layout for each item and used the `onClickListener` of the exposed view in the item layout. They checkbox-ing and state of the checkbox is working fine, by, I've got about 50 items on the list, and when I select the first one, the 7th or 8th item also gets selected, and selecting 2nd item does so for the 8th and 9th item.  So, I though, I wasn't doing this correctly. Please point me what could be wrong with this:

The adapter I'm using for my `recyclerView` is like this:

```
package com.squeezy.www.custom_widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squeezy.www.Main.squeezyDBHelper;
import com.squeezy.www.R;
import com.squeezy.www.Utils.utilities;
import com.squeezy.www.interfaces.AdditionInterface;

public class mAdapter_data extends BaseCursorAdapter<mAdapter_data.addDataViewHolder> {

    Context mContext =  null;
    String mDataTitle = null;
    String mDataPath = null;
    int mDataFK = -1;
    AdditionInterface<Integer> AdditionInterface = null;


    public mAdapter_data(){
        super(null);
    }

    public mAdapter_data(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        super(cursor);
        mContext = context;
        try{
            AdditionInterface = (AdditionInterface<Integer>)mContext;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("mAdapter_data::", "Data addition interface");
            return;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public addDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View addDataView =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.m_playlist_item_with_checkbox_layout,
                                parent, false);
        return new addDataViewHolder(addDataView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final addDataViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
        final String DataTitle = cursor.getString(squeezyDBHelper.SourceDataDBTitleIndex);
        final int DataFK = cursor.getInt(squeezyDBHelper.SourceDataDBPrimaryKeyIndex);
        final String DataPath = cursor.getString(squeezyDBHelper.SourceDataDBPathIndex);
        holder.DataTitleView.setText(DataTitle);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );

        params.height = utilities.Device.getReferencedHeight(
                (AppCompatActivity)mContext,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.listItemMinimumHeightInDp )
        );

        holder.getBaseView().setLayoutParams(params);

        holder.getBaseView()
            .findViewById( R.id.C_listViewListener )
            .setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDataTitle = DataTitle;
                            mDataFK = DataFK;
                            mDataPath = DataPath;
                            CheckBox mItemCheckBox = holder.getBaseView()
                                            .findViewById(R.id.m_itemCheckbox);
                            if(mItemCheckBox.isChecked()){
                                mItemCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                                AdditionInterface.removeItem(DataFK);
                            }else{
                                mItemCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                                AdditionInterface.includeItem(DataFK);
                            }
                        }
                    } );
    }

    class addDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View baseView = null;
        TextView DataTitleView = null;

        addDataViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            DataTitleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_itemName);
            baseView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.C_listViewItemMainHolder);
        }

        public View getBaseView(){
            return baseView;
        }

    }
}
```

The BaseCursor adapter is:

```
package com.squeezy.www.custom_widgets;

import android.database.Cursor;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public abstract class BaseCursorAdapter<V extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<V> {
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private boolean mDataValid;
    private int mRowIDColumn;

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(V holder, Cursor cursor);

    public BaseCursorAdapter(Cursor c){
        setHasStableIds(true);
        swapCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(V holder, int position){
        if(!mDataValid){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot bind view holder when cursor is in invalid state");
        }

        if(!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position "+position+"when trying to bind view holder");
        }

        onBindViewHolder(holder,mCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mDataValid) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if(!mDataValid){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot lookup item id when cursor is in invalid state.");
        }

        if(! mCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position "+position+"when trying to get an item id");
        }
        return mCursor.getLong(mRowIDColumn);
    }


    public Cursor getItem(int position) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot lookup item id when cursor is in invalid state.");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position " + position + " when trying to get an item id");
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor){
        if(newCursor == mCursor){
            return;
        }

        if(newCursor != null){
            mCursor = newCursor;
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, getItemCount());
            mCursor = null;
            mRowIDColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the layout for the item used in the `RecyclerView` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/C_listViewItemMainHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/datalist_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/shadow_effect"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spacer"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".17"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_datalist_with_bg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m_itemName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/iconForegroundBaseColor"
        android:textScaleX="1.1"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/datalist_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/m_itemCheckbox"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".34"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/datalist_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/datalist_icon" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/m_itemCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="@fonts/montserrat2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/iconForegroundBaseColor"
        app:buttonTint="@color/iconForegroundBaseColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/datalist_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/datalist_icon"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/C_listViewListener"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/datalist_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/datalist_icon">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shadow_effect"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:alpha=".55"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shadow_semi_circular_top_to_down" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:alpha=".7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/m_itemCheckbox"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/datalist_icon"
         />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using

```
private SparseBooleanArray itemStateArray= new SparseBooleanArray();
```

Replace below lines

```
  if(mItemCheckBox.isChecked()){
     mItemCheckBox.setChecked(false);
     AdditionInterface.removeItem(DataFK);
  }else{
     mItemCheckBox.setChecked(true);
     AdditionInterface.includeItem(DataFK);
  }
```

With

```
 if(mItemCheckBox.isChecked()){
     mItemCheckBox.setChecked(false);
     AdditionInterface.removeItem(DataFK);
     itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, false);
  }else{
     mItemCheckBox.setChecked(true);
     AdditionInterface.includeItem(DataFK);
     itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, true);
  }
```

In onBindViewHolder method, add below lines

```
  CheckBox mItemCheckBox = holder.getBaseView()
  .findViewById(R.id.m_itemCheckbox);

    if (itemStateArray.get(position, false)) {
        mItemCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    }else {
        mItemCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    }
```

Comment: This would work as state in this answer, if I hadn't extended the RecyclerView for a cursorAdapter, I'm quite confused how to make it work for a cursorAdapter. Do you think I could do that, please give me some pointers.

Comment: You can create a model class for the values you are needing from DB. In that model class you can keep a field name isChecked. This will be good approach. My answer is accroding to your code, as there is no model class for the data, you are directly getting data from DB in adapter.

Comment: yes, but the position parameter is not available in my class, how to get that from the superClass?

Comment: You can get it via callbacks.

Comment: could you please give me a little background on why this happens anyways? It seems not just RecycleView adapter, but also listview adapter/listviews have this problem as well

Comment: This happens because recyclerview recycled the views, with this already used view is used again when it goes out of screen. We can stop recyclerview to recycle the views but it will consume more memory and if number of items are more, this will let app to crash too. same happens in the case of listview.

Comment: but, listview would instantiate everything there at the time of setting it, isn't it? In which case the checkbox shouldn't be check, isn't it? Since listview doesn't reuse it views we use recyclerView for large items, isn't it? So, why would this problem occur in listviews?